# The use "that is it" and "that is all" in context

Tags: difference, phrases

Tell me please if there is any difference between *that is it* and *that is all* in the following sentence.

> I have only done half of my homework, **that is all**.
>
> I have only done half of my homework, **that is it**.

Comment: Note that native speakers don't ***make*** homework - they ***do*** it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: *I've only done half my homework, that's all.*

...is a "relatively credible" utterance, in that a native speaker *might* say this with the meaning you intend. But in practice few people would include the (completely redundant, imho) final clause - not least because it clashes with the meaning *normally* conveyed by *[statement], **that's all***.

To illustrate that point, a context in which #1 would be *perfectly* natural for a native speaker might be a reply to your mother saying *Your teacher just phoned and asked me to go and see her to discuss your performance at school. **What's going on**?* (even better, ***What's this all about***?).

> *[statement], **that's all***
>    means
>    *[statement] is true, **but it's not important***.

---

Correspondingly, the "tag" clause ***That's it*** has its own idiomatically established implications, so here's a slightly *different* context where a native speaker might reasonably come out with...

> 2: *I've only done half my homework. That's it!*.

Suppose you overheard your mother on the phone (talking the teacher, as above), and you asked yourself: *I wonder why my teacher called my mother?* Then you suddenly thought of a likely explanation...

> *[statement], **that's it.***  (more commonly ***That's it!*** [statement]
>    means
>   *[statement] is **the answer / solution / explanation I was looking for***

Answer (score 0):

> "I have only made half of my homework, **that is all**."

I don't want to tell anything else about this situation. I think you can understand me without more words.

> "I have only made half of my homework, **that is it**."

This is a fact. This have some reasons, but I don't know what can I say else.

This is a difference. As far as I can understand these sentences.